# Is there a way to redirect a user if a x509 certificate is not selected when going to website?

Tags: ssl, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am currently working in IBM's Domino(8.52).  I have the website set up with SSL and to accept certificates.  For the time being I am allowing "Anonymous" access over SSL.  The user is prompted to select a certificate when trying to get to web site.  But if the user selects cancel button, the user is returned to web site as an Anonymous user.  Is there any way to control where the user will go if a certificate is NOT selected?  I would like a server wide solution but would like any possible coding ideas.

V/R,

Kev

Comment: A redirect happens at the HTTP layer after the SSL session has been established first. Certificate validation happens during the SSL handshake before the client is allowed to send an HTTP request. To do what you are asking, the server would have to allow the SSL session to proceed without a certificate, and then the server would have to look at the SSL session to see which certificate(s) it is using when processing the client's HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As it is set now on server all http requests are redirected to https. The server authentication settings allow for Certificates, Username/Password and Anonymous. So if I do not select a certificate, I am redirected to site as an anonymous user.  No sure if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

How's the weather in VA?
The problem is that you are using the promoteunknowncerttoanonymous=1 ini setting; so you will not see the names on cert of users unless they have a corresponding x.509 loaded in the person doc.
Remove the ini setting, Disallow anonymous and username/password from both 80 and 443 in server doc, make sure your root x.509 cert is in the keyring, and you should start seeing the usernames from the certs.  You will now need to manage the Default setting in all db ACLs, and Anonymous will not be used.